# server unable to find route to api.twitter.com

Tags: networking

5 minutes ago, my server was unable to find route to api.twitter.com. `mtr` showed a blank screen. `/etc/init.d/networking restart` fixed the problem but I would like to understand what went wrong so that I can troubleshoot it more precisely next time. Any ideas ?

**UPDATE** : here is what the host command `shows`:

```
host api.twitter.com
api.twitter.com has address 199.16.156.199
api.twitter.com has address 199.16.156.40
api.twitter.com has address 199.16.156.104
```

after flushing the cache, one route changes:

```
host api.twitter.com
api.twitter.com has address 199.16.156.40
api.twitter.com has address 199.16.156.104
api.twitter.com has address 199.16.156.231
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see api.twitter.com has a multiple A records

```
# host api.twitter.com 216.187.125.130
Using domain server:
Name: 216.187.125.130
Address: 216.187.125.130#53
Aliases:

api.twitter.com has address 199.59.150.9
api.twitter.com has address 199.59.149.199
api.twitter.com has address 199.59.149.232

# host api.twitter.com 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

api.twitter.com has address 199.16.156.199
api.twitter.com has address 199.16.156.72
api.twitter.com has address 199.16.156.231
```

So it is possible that one node of the "cluster" has failed and all packets tried to reach failed node. As you can see each route has TTL

```
# ip ro get 199.59.150.9
199.59.150.9 via 209.15.xxx.xxx dev em1  src 209.15.xxx.xxx
    cache  mtu 1500 advmss 1460 hoplimit 64

# ip -s route show cache 199.16.156.231
199.59.150.9 via 209.15.xxx.xxx dev em1  src 192.168.207.10
    cache  users 1 used 38 age 17sec ipid 0x7f34 mtu 1500 advmss 1460 hoplimit 64
199.59.150.9 from 209.15.xxx.xxx via 209.15.xxx.xxx dev em1
    cache  users 1 age 20sec mtu 1500 advmss 1460 hoplimit 64
```

I think you can use the following command to clean your cache

```
# ip route flush cache 199.59.150.9
```

You can get more info at http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ipv4-route-cache-linux.html

Comment: Interesting. If fails again, I'm going to update my answer with what I get with `host`

Comment: flushing the cache does work

Comment: the problem keeps coming back though. It looks like twitter is having problems: https://dev.twitter.com/status

Comment: Please have a look at this question : http://serverfault.com/questions/578122/linux-caches-route-with-ips-of-machine-it-has-no-access-to , I'm still struggling with this problem...