# linux caches route with IPs of machine it has no access to

Tags: linux, networking, cache, route, twitter

I have a VPN with a gateway, and an application server.
The app server only knows about the gateway of the VPN. The gateway of the VPN knows about the gateway of the physical network the vms are hosted on.

Problem: I can't reach api.twitter.com from the application server.
Observation : the cache is filled with entries showing *the physical gateway* IP address. Here is an excerpt :

```
ip -s route show cache 199.16.156.40
199.16.156.40 via 37.59.245.62 dev eth0  src 10.1.4.20 
    cache <redirected>  used 170 age 22sec ipid 0x9e49
199.16.156.40 from 10.1.4.20 via 37.59.245.62 dev eth0 
    cache <redirected>  age 25sec ipid 0x9e49
```

IPs beginning with 199 are twitter IPs. `37.59.245.62` is the IP of the physical gateway. `10.1.4.20` is the VPN IP of the VPN's gateway.

The IP of the physical gateway only appears for entries dealing with twitter's servers.

Why does this machine cache routes with IPs it does not have direct access to ?

[Previous question showing that flushing the cache solves the problem temporarily](https://serverfault.com/questions/577005/server-unable-to-find-route-to-api-twitter-com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this [somewhere else](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125066/653), and it turns out the solution was to turn off ICMP redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it cache? The same reason caches are used in any other situation, to prevent the overhead of a route lookup. The reason you're seeing "external" gateways are more than likely ICMP messages coming back informing you that the that IP is unavailable.

Comment: What I don't get is why linux caches this route. In the demo environment, when I ping twitter, it caches the VPN gateway IP, which makes sense, because it knows how to go there...

Comment: I'm guessing it only gets that secondary gateway information from ICMP messages.

Comment: Hum... if I flush the cache and ping twitter, the cache is sane (which means the problem does not happen with ICMP messages, which have to do with ping and with ping only, am I right ?). So it means it must be the call I make in my php application which causes the problem. I'm going to try and reproduce it with a very small php script.

Comment: Well, ICMP is how a router tells you that it can't send your traffic, so I am assuming that this information is coming back from routers a bit "further out" than your local gw..

Comment: ok... interesting, I guess I'll need to read a bit more on ICMP... +1